# How do I dynamically load an SVG into a TWebImageControl component?

Tags: delphi, svg, tms-web-core

I have a TMS Web Core application with a `TWebImageControl` component on it and I'm trying to load an SVG Image (SVG Code) into the `TWebImageControl` component during run-time, but I'm not sure how.

I'm easily able to load the SVG during design-time by simply loading it into the `Picture` property:

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core TWebImageControl Component]

But how would I do this during run-time if I have the SVG Code?

Let's assume I have a String Variable that contains all the SVG XML Code. How do I take this String Variable and load the SVG into the `TWebImageControl` component?